# Distribution of binomial with poisson-distributed trials

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Assume there is an underlying process, $K$, governed by a Poisson distribution, $K\sim Poisson(\lambda)$. We observe realizations this process, but with an imperfect count detection device with failure rate, $p$. I.e. for $k$ counts actually produced by the underlying process, we observe $\tilde{K}=\tilde{k}$ counts, where $\tilde{K}\sim Binomial(k,1-p)$.

What is observed distribution of counts, $P(\tilde{K}=\tilde{k})$?

$P(\tilde{K}=\tilde{k})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(\tilde{K}=\tilde{k}|k)P(K=k)$

So far I get a diverging sum. This sum should converge, no? Note that we should specially treat the $k=0$ since in this case $P(\tilde{K}=\tilde{k}|k=0)=\delta_{0,\tilde{k}}$.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda(1-p)$. No need to perform the summation; you're just reducing the rate by a factor of $1-p$.

Comment: ok...that makes intuitive sense. The explicit approach I tried involves finding the trick that eliminates the combinatoric factors. By the way, is this simple rescaling a special property of the Poisson? What happens to the variance, say, for distributions where it isn't the same as the mean, e.g. for a negative binomial-distributed variable?

Comment: @puelmato: Yes, it's a special property of the Poisson distribution. With $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}=1$, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}k=pn$, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}k^2=p^2n^2+p(1-p)n$, the variance of $k$ is $\operatorname{Var}(k)=E[k^2]-E[k]^2=p^2E[n^2]+p(1-p)E[n]-p^2E[n]^2=p^2 \operatorname{Var}(n)+p(1-p)E[n]$. Note that $p(1-p)$ is the variance of the Bernoulli experiments that determine the detection.